# NSAutoreleasePool drain releases +1 more than the number of sent autorelease messages

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, nsautoreleasepool, nszombie

I've been having trouble debugging an iPhone app that crashes in a reproducible way.

**Short story:**
A custom `UIViewController` is allocated and pushed onto a `UINavigationController`'s stack.
Some time later the `UIViewController` is poped from the stack.
The very next push of a `UIViewController` onto the stack crashes the app.

The standard procedure for any crash is using the Instruments with `NSZombie` enabled.
Upon inspection of the object's history some is revealed that I fail to understand:

- the object receives 2 (two) `autorelease` messages and
- the `NSAutoreleasePool`'s drain method send 3 (three) release messages

So far, the only way to prevent crashes is to NOT send 1 (one) release message to the object in question and thus raising a red flag for memory leaks, only that it doesn't leak.

Is there any other solution that I've overlooked?

**Update:** As one of you pointed out the obvious:

> You have a problem in your code. Nothing to do with autorelease pool drain.

It turned out that the first `UIViewController` was passed as a delegate to the `UINavigationController` hence my confusion when the `Zombie` call was coming from the navigation controller itself.

I should me more careful next time before asking the wrong question.

Comment: I think you should go ahead and try ARC (automatic reference counting) and @autoreleasepool introduced by Apple in iOS5 and Lion. It's only a few days before iOS 5 goes into production, and Lion is already there.

Comment: Short answer: You have a problem in your code. Nothing to do with autorelease pool drain.

Comment: The normal way is: 1. allocate viewcontroller 2. push it onto a navigation controller 3. release it. For what do you need autorelease?

Comment: @ott I am going about it the normal way and not using `autorelease`.